# Usage of condition variable and create a simple reusable class

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, condition-variable

I have created a class using condition variable where I can create an object and use it instead of writing the implementation of the condition variable.

Below is my code. Now the functionality works as expected.

I see some issues if I run valgrind.
So I have two requests.

1. Please check the class implementation of the class and confirm if there can be any issues.
2. There is a "still reachable" error in valgrind if I run a gtest with this code. I checked online and found that "still reachable" issue can be ignored and moreover this problem is shown even if I do not add any code inside the test case (empty test case). So I am not too much worried about this error.

here is my code.

```
//ConditionalVariable.h


#ifndef SOURCE_MBUTILS_CONDITIONALVARIABLE_H_
#define SOURCE_MBUTILS_CONDITIONALVARIABLE_H_

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

class ConditionalVariable {
public:
    ConditionalVariable();
    virtual ~ConditionalVariable();

    /**
     * wait for the condition to reset from thread 1
     */
    void waitForCondition();

    /**
     * wait for the condition to reset from thread 1 for timeout (msec)
     * returns false if timeout, true otherwise
     */
    bool waitForCondtion(std::uint32_t timeout);

    /**
     * reset the condition from thread 1, normally after the wait is over!
     */
    void resetCondition();

    /**
     * set the condition from thread 2
     */
    void setTheCondition();

    /**
     * get current condition state
     */
    bool isConditionNowSet();
private:
    std::mutex _mtx;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    bool _condition;
};

#endif /* SOURCE_MBUTILS_CONDITIONALVARIABLE_H_ */
```

```
//ConditionalVariable.cpp

#include "ConditionalVariable.h"

ConditionalVariable::ConditionalVariable(): _condition(false)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

ConditionalVariable::~ConditionalVariable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void ConditionalVariable::waitForCondition()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
    _cv.wait(lock, [this]{ return _condition;});
}

bool ConditionalVariable::waitForCondtion(std::uint32_t timeout)
{
    auto timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + (std::chrono::milliseconds) timeout;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
    return _cv.wait_until(lock, timePoint, [this]{return _condition;});
}
void ConditionalVariable::resetCondition() {
    //make the condition false to reset!
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
    _condition = false;
}

void ConditionalVariable::setTheCondition()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
    _condition = true;
    _cv.notify_one();
}
bool ConditionalVariable::isConditionNowSet()
{
    return _condition;
}
```

Below error is from valgrind

[image]

Comment: Any access to your condition variable should be blocked behind the mutex. You're not doing this in `isConditionNowSet`.

Comment: This is a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: do you mean a  `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);` to be used here also?

Comment: This isn't a condition variable anymore.  Figure out if you want a semaphore, counting semaphore, a gate, or whatever.  The existence of reset in that API looks like a bad plan, as the order of set/reset/set cannot be guaranteed, leading to lost signals.  Your constructor is meh; initialize stuff in class declband default it.   Notify one is wrong unless wait resets.  Wait is a conceptually const operation (make mutex mutable)

Comment: 'I checked online and found that "still reachable" issue can be ignored'. Are you certain? You need to make sure that the memory is in a one-off allocation otherwise your app could run out of memory if there is a loop allocating "still reachable" memory. If it is in the gtest code then it is probably safe to ignore.

Comment: Yes, it is in libglib code somehwere, it is very strange that even with below code I see the issue. So I have stopped worrying about it.


```cpp
TEST(TestSuite, Testcase)
{
   // no code inside.
}
```